# Customize column header of a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, scrollbar, cell

I am using a `JTable` to display data with custom `TableCellRenderer`.

Everything works fine despite there appears a small "area" in the right upper corner when having a vertical scrollbar. I want to render that area transparent, is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to render that area transparent, is this possible?

Not really sure what you mean. That area is rendered transparent. All you see is the background of the scrollpane.

However you can place your own component in that area if you wish. Check out the section from the Swing tutorial on [Providing Custom Decorations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html#decorations) for a JScrollPane.

The example shows how to add a custom component to the top/right of the scrollpane using:

```
pictureScrollPane.setCorner(JScrollPane.UPPER_RIGHT_CORNER, new Corner());
```